# Verify that the currently authenticated windows user has delegation rights

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-authentication, impersonation

Given that I have a WCF service using windows authentication, and I want to impersonate them and call another WCF service, like so:

```
using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    // call another WCF service
}
```

I've set all the config settings and it works fine, as long as on the client side,they include the following line:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

But, how do I verify before trying to make the call that the user token has delegation rights? i.e. the client, which I don't control, has set the AllowedPersonationLevel?

If they haven't set it, all sorts of weird exceptions get thrown (like cannot load assembly X etc).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    if (UserDoesntHaveDelegationRights())
        throw new SecurityException("No delegation rights");

    // call another WCF service
}
```

Note that `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel`  is always equal to `TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation`, so that unfortunately is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be some confusion here in definitions. In terms of [impersonation levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a windows identity can be:

- Impersonated - the service can impersonate the user locally
- Delegated - the service can impersonate the user remotely

The ability to delegate is so powerful that its highly restricted in Active Directory:

1. The Client has to allow delegation
2. The service account which is doing the delegation must be marked as "*trusted for delegation*" in Active Directory.

Here's how to [enable an account for delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739474%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It requires a Active Directory domain admin to the make the change. Every corporate environment that I've ever worked in has a policy that does not allow Delegation.

Back to your question:

**So while `TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation` exists, its considered a security risk and rarely (if ever) used. `TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation` is the highest level that you will probably ever get.**

`TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation` is useful. You can still connect to a database or make a remote service call as the impersonated user. But a remote service (not on the same box) can't impersonate the user a second time. The basic rule of thumb is "impersonation enables two machines hops". If the user's credentials have to "hop" farther, it will fail.

If you need to pass a user's credentials between many servers the best choice is a federated security model such as Windows Identity Foundation (WIF). See [Identity Management in Active Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel != TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation) ...
```

Comment: Yea, that is what I thought - but WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel is always equal to Impersonation