# Kerberos and WindowsIdentity impersonation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 web app (actually a blazor server app) and another ASP.NET Core 5 Web API, both running on IIS in a domain environment.

I have configured Windows auth so that users can authenticate with the Blazor server app, and this returns the expected domain user's identity from the `HttpContext`.

If I use the Web API through Swagger to get the users identity from the `HttpContext`, I also get the expected domain user's identity.  However if naively call from the Blazor server app using the `HttpClient` (given by DI) to the Web API, I get the app pool identity for the user instead.

There are hundreds of posts on this subject and why this happens (i.e.)

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17828

[.Net Core WindowsIdentity impersonation does not seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839845/net-core-windowsidentity-impersonation-does-not-seem-to-be-working)

However my question is essentially even if I do manage to get the stars to align and get all the infrastructure config correct is there any way to get the middleware to provide an `HttpClient` that is already "impersonated" or am I forced to wrap every use of `HttpClient` something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511109/29411

```
IPrincipal p = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

HttpResponseMessage result = null;

if (p.Identity is WindowsIdentity wid)
{
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(wid.AccessToken, async () =>
                     {
                         result = await _client.GetAsync("APIController/Action");
                     });
}
```

Comment: You could try to use a named client integrating the impersonation logic.
Look at this answer for delegated client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380054/verify-that-the-currently-authenticated-windows-user-has-delegation-rights

Comment: I think the code you post is the most suitable method at present. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675503/14162739) explains that why need to wrap every use of httpclient, though it recommend use webclient.

Answer (score 1):

**.Net 5 running Impersonated**
(I am running this in Blazor Server)

I have only recently solved this so at present I think everything will need to be wrapped but I'll update if I find anything that solves that.

I have seen a lot of references to using an IHttpConextAccessor and lots of problems with this being null. This article from Microsoft suggests that this shouldn’t be used (Certainly in Blazor)
[MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-and-shared-state)

Solution:
To get the user to impersonate use the AuthenticationStateProvider and get the user from this and cast to a WindowsIDentity to retrieve the AccessToken.
This works in both a service and a razor component.
Inject the AuthenticationStateProvider and then in your method use the following code:

```
    var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;
    var userToImpersonate = (WindowsIdentity)user.Identity;
    
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(userToImpersonate.AccessToken, async () => 
  {
    
      // Your Code in here
    
  }
```

Comment: That isn't working for me (at least not yet, this may be an IIS config issue).  Even if I did get it working I'd really prefer to get my HttpClient instance already impersonated using DI.

Comment: Indeed, me too. It's on the list but I spent long enough getting to this stage and I need to get my other work done! I will revisit it though when I move forward using this.

Comment: If you ever get this working with DI please post it here:)  I have worked around the issue but it is a good workaround so I'd be interested if you ever got this wokring with DI.

Comment: For folks that have HttpContextAccessor as null - I ran into this and didn't know I needed to add services.AddHttpContextAccessor();.